# How to wait for webpage to fully load before proceeding script?

Tags: applescript

How do you wait for a webpage to fully load before proceeding the script?

I know you can use delay 4 if you would want it to wait 4 seconds but this is not safe enough.

In VBA you have a simple code that always works and it goes like this:

```
Dim x As String
x = "https://na6.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=" & Range("T34").Value & "&parentname=" & Range("T35").Value & "&retURL=%2F0018000000sKz8K%3Fpb0%3Dtrue"

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate (x)
    IE.Visible = True
    SetParent IE.Hwnd, Application.Hwnd

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
```

What would be the equivalent of this on mac with safari for applescript?

I´ve seen many versions on the net but only workarounds similar to the delay or for a specify value to return or to count words on the page and so on.

I simply want the above version which is 100% perfect.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: There is no "ready state" status for Safari / Chrome / Firefox that you can get from them via js or applescript.  I have great success with the "repeat until a value is loaded onto the site content" method. I recall posted one on stack as an answer at some point.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the ready state of a page by calling "document.readyState" from either Safari or Chrome.

```
tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    tell current tab of window 1 to set URL to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500011/how-to-wait-for-webpage-to-fully-load-before-proceeding-script"

    set the_state to missing value
    repeat until the_state is "complete"
        set the_state to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
        log "busy"
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    log "complete"
end tell
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on 10.6.8 with Safari Version 5.1.10 (6534.59.10). It says complete but page is still loading in safari.

Comment: I added an extra delay of 2 seconds at the end. It seemed to need this to execute the next part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

I do it in this way:

```
tell document 1 of application "Safari"  
  set URL to ""  
  set URL to "/slowly loading page/"  
  repeat until name is not "about:blank"  
  end repeat  
end tell
```

Or, even easier:

```
tell front document of application "Safari"  
  set URL to "/slowly loading page/"  
  repeat until length of (source as text) is not 0  
  end repeat  
end tell
```

Furthermore, there’s no need to do it without any delay:

```
repeat until length of (source as text) is not 0  
  delay 0.5  
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

Googled a bit and found this code that works for Safari Version 5.1.10 (6534.59.10) on Snow Leopard.

From http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=35176

```
tell application "Safari"
   activate
   repeat until SafariWindowHasLoaded(1) of me is true
   end repeat
   beep
end tell

on SafariWindowHasLoaded(inWindowIndex)
   tell application "System Events" to ¬
       tell application process "Safari"    
           set theStatusText to name of static text 1 of group 1 of window inWindowIndex as text
           if theStatusText begins with "Contacting" or ¬
               theStatusText begins with "Loading" or ¬
               theStatusText begins with "Waiting" then
               set theReturnValue to false
           else
               set theReturnValue to true
           end if
       end tell
   return theReturnValue
end SafariWindowHasLoaded
```

Only problem I had was that this script was for an older version of Safari and the Status Bar element was in a different group than mine.

At http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071015132722688 it was suggested to change it to

`static text 1 of group 2`

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I find getting the JavaScript "document.readyState" value the best way to determine if a page has finished loading, but that requires Safari to **Developer > Allow JavaScript from Apple Events**.  Since that's is a security risk, I adjust Safari's preferences to enable it when it's needed, then disable it.

```
tell application "Safari" to open location ¬
     "https://neeva.com/search?q=demon%20cats&c=Image&src=typedquery" -- random site
Wait_For_Safari()
--Feed cats and do other worthy things.

on Wait_For_Safari()
    tell application "System Events" to set originatingApp to ¬
        name of first application process where frontmost is true --in case we aren't executing from Safari
    Allow_Apple_Events() --enable AllowJavaScriptFromAppleEvents so we can get JS's "document.readyState"
    tell application "Safari"
        set readyState to missing value
        repeat until readyState is "complete" --wait for readyState = complete
            set readyState to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        delay 0.2
    end tell
    Disallow_Apple_Events() --Disable AllowJavaScriptFromAppleEvents so our pants aren't down
    tell application originatingApp to activate --return to wherever we started
end Wait_For_Safari

on Allow_Apple_Events()
    do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.Safari AllowJavaScriptFromAppleEvents 1" --1 = enabled
end Allow_Apple_Events

on Disallow_Apple_Events()
    do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.Safari AllowJavaScriptFromAppleEvents 0" --0 = disabled
end Disallow_Apple_Events
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses macOS accessibility functions to check if the "reload this page" button is present in the Safari toolbar, which only appears once the page has finished loading. I've tested it on macOS Ventura 13.6 and Safari 17.0 and it works great.

I took this from the user robertfern on macscripter.net [here](https://www.macscripter.net/t/safari-export-as-pdf-with-endless-repeat-until-exists/74041/4)

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
        process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
```