# Safari (Mac OS X) - Custom extension (or script) with no key / no certificate, only for MY browser

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, safari-extension

So the situation is something like this:

- Pinterest blocks content if you are not a member.
- Wired blocks content if you have an ad blocker.
- And so on.

Conveniently, you can get rid of said blocks with a few simple `CSS` overrides.

I'm trying to do one of the following:

1. Create a Safari extension (*WITHOUT* a certificate or key)

   I've made a couple extensions that work exactly as I'd like (without paying $150 or whatever to become a developer), but the extensions disappear when I close Safari and later reopen it. I then have to go through the `Develop>Show Extensions Editor` menus and re-install it. Every. Single. Time.

   I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158656/installed-safari-extensions-disappear-after-restarting-safari) post that said it's to do with the keychain, but mine does not have anthing related to `extensions`.

   I tried adding the custom extension directly to `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/`, as well as modifying `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist` to reflect the addition, but that didn't work out. The zipped extension remained in the Extensions folder, but my attempt at modifying the `.plist` obviously fell short. Probably due to the missing key in the xml for the extension.

   I have no interest in publishing these extensions. They are solely to improve my own person user experience. I don't see why I shouldn't be able to install as many of my own *custom* extensions as I'd like, without the need to fork out cash.
2. The other option is to write a script, in my local environment (i.e. on my computer), that Safari can call every time the page loads.

   It's like it sounds. Either write a custom script that Safari calls after the page has loaded, or modify Safari itself at the source to perform the operations.

   I'm not sure how to go about this route. I tried messing around with various [applescripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500011/how-to-wait-for-webpage-to-fully-load-before-proceeding-script), but I'm still not quite in the right place.

Any thoughts on how I can either a) inject JS into the page or b) override the CSS, all without jumping through hoops and dishing out my month's food.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not possible without any certificate.

However, you could [use Xcode to create a JS or CSS injecting Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/CreatingandTestingYourFirstSafariAppExtension.html). The extension will be signed with an ad-hoc certificate, which only lasts one Safari session. You can replace the ad-hoc certificate with a (free) Mac Development certificate ([can be created via Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW6) for a limited number of devices, but you'll need a free developer account). Your extension will then be permanent as long as your Mac Development certificate is valid.